# Janky on an Ubuntu Server

Tags: ruby, github, continuous-integration

I am looking to install Janky (https://github.com/github/janky) on an Ubuntu server. The installation guide however only specifies how to install it on Heroku.

The reason for installing on Ubuntu is due to the fact that our CI server is not accessible from outside our network.

has any one done this before, or can any one point me in the right direction. This seems to be a Ruby web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a [rack app](http://ruby.about.com/od/rack/a/Using-Rack.htm) you should be able to just run

```
rackup -I lib config.ru
```

from the project root.  Also, since it was designed to be a heroku app, you'll want to configure the environment variables locally, so instead of

```
heroku config:add VARIABLE=value
```

you'll do

```
export VARIABLE=value
```